# React, How to output raw `null` and `undefined` and empty string `''`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

html:

`<p>{null}</p>`

`<p>{this.state.someVar}</p>`

I want to them output like this:

`null`

`undefined`

Here is my solution:

`<p>{JSON.stringify(null)}</p>`

`<p>{typeof this.state.someVar === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : this.state.someVar}</p>`

Is there a better solution?

Comment: For React or for Angular?

Comment: I would suggest create a wrapper function and pass value to it. Then you can have a `if..else` ladder for every case. This would keep html clean and make you function configurable

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your use of `JSON.stringify()`, but more direct

```
<p>{ String(myVar) }</p>
```

Comment: How to output raw html like this: `<textarea>` ? Thanks!